# Any reason to run Grails on linux vs. windows?

Tags: grails

I know that developing with Ruby on Rails in Windows is not always easy, and I read lots of complaints that it just isn't fully compatible with Windows.

Is grails the same? Does it matter whether I dev on Windows/Linux/OSX?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the OS that you prefer. I've been developing Grails apps on Windows at work (because I have to) for a few years. Outside of work I use Linux exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Where I am, people use Linux and Windows to develop in Grails. There has been no problem regarding OS specific stuff.

In fact you should be more concerned about the Java flavor and version you have (some linux distros have an open source implementation), and, of course, the Grails version.

My advices:

- Pick any OS you want (I even use both on the same Grails project with no problems)
- Try to use the Oracle JDK (for me openJDK is a bit slower)
- Pick a Grails version and stick to it as much as you can (preferably don't change the version it can be painful to upgrade a project)

Answer (score 0):

I developed Grails apps on Windows and Linux. IMHO, use the OS you'll be the most productive with and has the toolset you want. Linux is definitively more friendly to programmers in terms of available tools in general. Windows developer community is coming up with interesting project such as Chocolatey and Console2 among other things. I personally prefer Linux because it offers me a lot more to learn besides just learning Grails for example.